# scala quasiquotes string variable lifting in multiple steps

Tags: scala, scala-quasiquotes, lifting

this is what i want:

```
scala> var x:Int = 10
x: Int = 10

scala> var y:Int = 20
y: Int = 20

scala> val ret = q"return $x>$y"
ret: universe.Return = return 10.$greater(20)

scala> val result1 = toolbox.compile(ret)()
result1: Any = false
```

But the problem is that I will be getting the expression $x>$y in a string var, like

```
scala> m
res20: String = $x>$y
```

And then I want to perform the operation as,

```
var ret = q"return $m"
```

but this return:

```
scala> var ret = q"return $m"
ret: universe.Return = return "$x>$y"
```

which is not serving the purpose. How can I get the value of x and y in the last step instead **$x and $y.**

Answer (score 0):

You can mix quasiquotes and `ToolBox.parse` to achieve results mostly like what you are looking for:

```
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val toolbox = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.mkToolBox()

val s = "10>20"
val ret = q"return ${toolbox.parse(s)}"
// reflect.runtime.universe.Return = return 10.$greater(20)
toolbox.eval(ret)
// Any = false
```

Making use of your values as variables:

```
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val toolbox = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.mkToolBox()
val x = 10
val y = 20
val m = "x>y"
val ret = q"return ${toolbox.parse(m)}"
// reflect.runtime.universe.Return = return x.$greater(y)
```

If you evaluate `q"return ${toolbox.parse(m)}"` you will see the error because `x` and `y` are not in scope.

```
scala> toolbox.eval(q"return ${toolbox.parse(m)}")
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:

object > is not a member of package x ...
```

To fix that:

```
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val toolbox = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.mkToolBox()
val q1 = q"val x = 10; val y = 20; "
val m = "x>y"
val ret = q"""
     |   ..$q1
     |   return ${toolbox.parse(m)}
     | """
toolbox.eval(ret)
// Any = false
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one more question here. The line: